# Changing a text format date to date formt

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a set of dates in multiple columns.

I need to format this cell to `DD-MM-YYYY`.

The date format to change from `"Mon Jun 01 10:06:35 2020"` to `01-06-2020` in google sheet

Please share the code in such a way that I can just use it in any google sheet.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecause.com/noattempt

Comment: Try to always add a minimal and reproducible example. What do you mean with `it can be used in any google sheet`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
function convertDate(x){
  const myDate = new Date(x);
  const day = myDate.getDate();
  const month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = myDate.getFullYear()
  const formattedDate = `${day < 10 ? "0"+day : day}-${month < 10 ? "0"+month : month}-${year}`;
  return formattedDate;
}

console.log(convertDate("Mon Jun 01 10:06:35 2020"));
//Output: "01-06-2020"
```